# Data Visualization tool for tracing Android log

Tags: android, uml, visualization, aspectj

This is a part of a project that I am working on. It includes modifying the .class files in the Android Source Code for Gingerbread 2.3.7 (irrelevant for the question)

I have modified the .class files using a custom weaver tool (did not use aspectJ) which works similar in terms of aspectJ weaver. What the tool does is that it inserts a line at the entry and exit of every class and method.

So when the log file is generated, it is something like this:

```
"Calling: public void <init>(android.content.Context context, android.util.AttributeSet attrs) in class: android.widget.TextView"
"Calling: public void <init>(android.content.Context context, android.util.AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) in class: android.widget.TextView"
"Calling: private void setTypefaceByIndex(int typefaceIndex, int styleIndex) in class: android.widget.TextView"
"Calling: public void setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface tf, int style) in class: android.widget.TextView"
"Calling: protected boolean getDefaultEditable() in class: android.widget.TextView"
"Calling: protected android.text.method.MovementMethod getDefaultMovementMethod() in class: android.widget.TextView"
"Calling: public int getTotalPaddingLeft() in class: android.widget.TextView"
"Calling: public android.graphics.drawable.Drawable[] getCompoundDrawables() in class: android.widget.TextView"
```

This is outputted to a log file. I need a Data Visualization tool that can make a UML or Sequence diagram of the trace(path) of hierarchy of classes using this log trace.

Basically a visual alternative of the trace. The sequence diagram is along the lines of:

```
Classname -> method() -> otherMethod() -> SomeOtherClass -> method() -> method2() -> OtherClass
```

All the class names and the method names are generated in the log file, thanks to the weaver. I have looked into a couple of tools like:
https://github.com/bedrin/jsonde

But they did not serve the purpose. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why didnt serve the purpose?

Comment: @Harald I am trying to run it on Ubuntu 10.04 . I am able to install the jar file, but its GUI is not coming up. The gingerbread build successfully runs on Ubuntu 10.04. Same cannot be said about the jsonde.